# Why doesn't this return a map with 100 keypairs?

Tags: clojure

I would expect 100 keypairs, but get six. Why?

```
(defn random-map-generator [size]
  (def theatom (atom {}))
  (dotimes [x size]
    (swap! theatom assoc 
      (keyword (nth ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"] (rand-int 6)))
      (rand-int 30)))
  @theatom)

(random-map-generator 100)
=> {:f 4, :a 29, :e 15, :c 23, :b 19, :d 28}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have only 6 unique keys. Once you assoc `:a` in there, any subsequent attempt to assoc another `:a` in there just overwrites the previous value. Keyword `:a` is identical to another `:a`, even if you dynamically create both.

Also, two unrelated comments:

- Don't use `def` within functions - use `let`
- Don't use atoms when you have a more functional alternative. In this case, it would be using `reduce`, or `into` + `map`, or even `loop`

Comment: To add, there's also `rand-nth` to get random element from coll. The original rewritten with `map` would be: `(defn random-map-generator [size]
  (let [alphabet ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"]]
    (->> (repeatedly (fn [] [(keyword (rand-nth alphabet)) (rand-int 6)]))
         (take size)
         (into {}))))`

Comment: Oh, of course! Unique keys! And the side points are so hepful (re: the use of `let` vs `def`, avoiding atoms. And thanks also for the `rand-nth` and an actual example.